# EJS includes not working

Tags: ejs

I have an EJS file called 'test.ejs', which contains:

```
<p>This is a test statement</p>
```

Then, I have another file called 'index.ejs' which is in the same folder as the other EJS file. Index.ejs contains:

```
<%- include ("test") %>
<p>Hello world</p>
```

However, when I load the page, I do not get any output. Instead, the page just loads endlessly.

My routes in Express are being handled properly and my controllers are working too. All this is tested.

Also, can someone refer me to good EJS documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<% include ./test %>
<p>Hello world</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

> try: <% include /pathname/test %>

Documentation is sparse but the official one works

http://www.embeddedjs.com/

or

http://ejs.co/